# Apigee - Retrieve App custom attribute after successful oauth2 authentification

Tags: api, oauth, apigee

I configured a simple API with Apigee with oauth2 authorization. In my API I use a custom ID to separate different clients. To be able to retrieve this custom id to my API I created a custom attribute in the developer App named "Tenant".

My oauth policy is pretty simple :

```
<OAuthV2 async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="ValidateOAuth">
    <DisplayName>ValidateOAuth</DisplayName>
    <FaultRules/>
    <Properties/>
    <Attributes />
    <ExternalAuthorization>false</ExternalAuthorization>
    <Operation>VerifyAccessToken</Operation>
    <SupportedGrantTypes/>
    <Tokens/>
</OAuthV2>
```

I created a conditional flow to apply this authorization when user doesn't use a public url of my API

```
<Flow name="Authorize">
    <Description/>
    <Request>
        <Step>
            <FaultRules/>
            <Name>ValidateOAuth</Name>
        </Step>
    </Request>
    <Response>
        <Step>
            <FaultRules/>
            <Name>EchoTenant</Name>
        </Step>
    </Response>
    <Condition>request.uri !~~ ".+(widget|tracker).+"</Condition>
</Flow>
```

In the response I prepared an Assign Message policy to add to the header my tenantId (where xxx need to be replaced with the correct variable)

```
<AssignMessage async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="EchoTenant">
    <AssignTo createNew="false" type="response"></AssignTo>
    <IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>true</IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>
    <Set>
        <Headers>
            <Header name="X-Tenant">xxx</Header>
        </Headers>
    </Set>
</AssignMessage>
```

In the doc I saw an example to retrieve developer attribute like email with 2 mores policies : accessEntity and extractVariables. I tried to use them but without success...
In my case I haven't access to the ApiKey, I only have an accessToken I think ? Is it possible with the accessToken to retrieve my custom app attribute ?

In this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21948465/in-apigee-how-to-get-a-custom-attribute-value-for-a-developer-using-the-accesse), [Mike Dunker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3182611/mike-dunker) wrote

> It really depends on the information you have at the time the proxy is
>   running. If you are using OAuth or API key validation (via the OAuthV2
>   and VerifyAPIKey policies), the custom attributes are automatically
>   populated after the token or API key is validated. In practice I find
>   that I rarely need to call AccessEntity.

I tried to use the trace tool to see informations sent after successful authorization but I didn't see my Tenant Id. Maybe there is a better solution for my problem
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use VerifyAccessToken to validate your OAuth token.  After VerifyAccessToken, try accessing `app.{custom_attribute_name}`.  You may not see this value in the trace tool, as there are many dozens of variables that are populated from VerifyAccessToken.

If you don't need VerifyAccessToken in your flow (in most cases you will), there is also GetOauthv2info which does the same-- more info [here](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/reference/get-oauth-v2-info-policy).  The variable will be `oauthv2client.{policy_name}.{custom_attribute_name}`